# detecting finger movement with Microsoft Kinect in c#

Tags: c#, kinect

Is it possible to detect finger movements with Kinect. I am able to detect skeleton and do some mouse movement and perform a click based on OTHER HAND location. I would like to implement the 'mouse click' using finger movements.

Is it possible with Microsoft Kinect sdk or with the other open source similar projects?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe the current revision of Kinect does not provide this level of percision at this time. In perhaps a future update this might be possible although I suspect that would require a hardware update similar the Wii-Plus add-on that Nintendo did. Of course there is one advantage that Nintendo did not have, I do believe the SDK/Xbox does all the calculations, Kinect simply sends the skeleton throught he bus ( I could be entirely wrong ).  This would explain the reason you have to use your entire "Foot" or "Hand" to perform an action in say the Kinect version of Wii Sports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it is only possible by using a hack; there is no official setting or API for it but it is possible to analyze the image data and find the fingers.

[Have a look here](http://kinect.dashhacks.com/finger-tracking)