# Detecting fingers in Kinect for windows sdk 1.5 c#

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm now detecting all the skeleton in a wpf application, I want to know how to detect the fingers to appear with the skeleton? I'm using microsoft Kinect for windows sdk ver 1.5

Many thanks

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926397/detecting-finger-movement-with-microsoft-kinect-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kinect unfortunately is not sensitive enough to recognize fingers so the library will not provide that as part of the skeleton.  Maybe the Kinect 2.0 rumored to come out with the Xbox 720 will be able to provide that level of detail.

Answer (score 5):

[Candescent NUI](http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/) might be what you're looking for. As OpenUserX03 said, however, the Kinect isn't ideal for this task. Perhabs you should have a look at the coming-up [LEAP](http://leapmotion.com/) technology, which specializes in finger detection.

Answer (score 1):

The cameras on the Kinect are not meant to be able to do joint tracking for the hands to that level of detail. Tracking the individual fingers is possible but wont be very reliable. To represent a players hand in the skeleton, you can check if the players hand is opened or closed. A possible way to see if the hand is open or closed would be to do pixel checks in an area surrounding the hand. This way with some tuning you could calculate how much of that area is the hand (using the depth and color stream) and how much is not. For example: If 40% of that area is the same depth as the hand joint, the hand is closed in a fist. If 70% of that area is the same depth as the hand joint, the hand is open. Then you could possibly use the angle of the elbow and wrist joint to be able to represent a closed or open hand at that angle on the skeleton.